# I need a solution like SQL Server trigger onDatabaseOnline or onServerStart

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a procedure in the database that needs to be executed upon server startup, after a database is connected or restored to the online state, or upon the first activity (login) of any user. Is there any solution other than using SQL Server Agent triggered daily at midnight?

Comment: There are probably solutions but what does your procedure do? Perhaps there's a better way of doing whatever that is

Comment: These are different things. 1 is an agent task that should start after *agent starts* (not at midnight) and the other 2 are server triggers (on different actions).

Comment: Though, like @siggemannen hints at, this has the smell of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: @ThomA Only Logon has a trigger option, and it runs on *every* logon. Database startup can have a trigger via SQL Agent, and `sp_procoption` runs a procedure at server startup.